# Holomorphic function and primitives

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, primitive-roots, holomorphic-functions

I need to prove that $\int_\gamma f'(z)/f(z)dz=0$ for any closed curve. It is given that f is holomorphic and satisfies $|f(z)-1|\lt1$ in the region. And we can assume $f'(z)$ is continuous.

I think that first I need to prove that $f'(z)/f(z)$ has a primitive, so that I can use the proposition to prove the integral is equal to 0.

But I don't know how to prove $f'/f$ has a primitive and how to use that inequality in my proof? Thanks.

Comment: The integrand is holomorphic; can you use the Cauchy integral theorem?

Comment: So using the Cauchy integral theorem, we know that it's integral over the closed curve would be zero and that means $f'/f$ has a primitive?

Answer (score 1):

The quotient $\;\frac{f'}f\;$ is analytic wherever $\;f\neq0\;$, and since this happens in the integration region (why?) Cauchy's Theorem gives the answer at once (I'm assuming you meant closed, simple and rectifiable curve)

Comment: So using the Cauchy integral theorem, we know that it's integral over the closed curve would be zero and that means $f'/f$ has a primitive?

Comment: @J.doe Well, yes: the primitive is easy: $\;\log f(z)\;$ , after choosing a suitable branch. Yet you don't even need to mention that when using Cauchy theorem...

Comment: Wait, why do we need $logf(z)$?

Comment: @J.doe We **don't**, as I said. It is just that $\;\left(\log f(z)\right)'=\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\;$ .

Comment: So $f'/f$ is analytic so it has a primitive, and as a result, we can use the proposition to prove the integral is equal to 0? But we don't use the inequality given in the problem?

Comment: @J.doe Once again: if you use Cauchy's THeorem you don't even need to mention "primitive function", and of course we do use the inequality! How otherwise could we deduce that $\;f\neq0\;$ ?

Comment: .... Sry about that...I missed that when I first read your comment.. Thanks!

Comment: But $\gamma$ can be any closed curve, so it means it doesn't have to be simple?

Comment: As long as $\gamma$ is contained in a simply connected open subset of the domain (on which $f \ne 0$), it doesn't matter whether it is simple or not.

Comment: @J.doe What arkeet wrote, though of course it is important the curve is "nice": piecewise differentiable and, I believe, rectifiab le (i.i with finite length).